# Verify signature always returns false

Tags: java, cryptography

In my application server sends a signed packet to client using UDP. Packet contains X509Encoded public key of the server. On receipt of this packet, client verifies the signature against the received data. My verify() always returns false. Following is the code. Please tell me what is wrong in the code.

```
//Drply.java    
public class Drply   implements Serializable, Cpacket {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private byte ptype;
private String name;
private byte[] bpub;
private String ip;
private byte[] bsign;

public Drply(String n, byte[] bp, String i, PrivateKey prk) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    name = n;
    bpub = bp;
    ip = i;
    ptype = (byte)2;

    bsign = genSignature(new String(name + bpub + ip + ptype).getBytes("UTF-8"), prk);
}

public byte[] genSignature(byte[] bdata, PrivateKey prk) {
    byte[] bsign = null;  
    try {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        sig.initSign(prk);  
        //update signature with data to be signed  
        sig.update(bdata);  
        //sign the data  
        bsign = sig.sign();  
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bsign;
}

public boolean verifySignature( ) throws InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
        X509EncodedKeySpec pkeyenc = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bpub);
        KeyFactory kfy = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pbk = kfy.generatePublic(pkeyenc);

        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(pbk);

        sig.update(new String(name.trim() + bpub + ip.trim() + ptype).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ret = sig.verify(bsign);

        System.out.println("Sig. matching: " + ret );
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}

//Server.java

public class TestServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    KeyPairGenerator kg;
    kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair kp = kg.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey pvk = kp.getPrivate();
    PublicKey pbk = kp.getPublic();
    X509EncodedKeySpec pkeyenc = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pbk.getEncoded());
    byte[] bpubKey= pkeyenc.getEncoded(); 


    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 6000));
    System.out.println("Waiting....");  
    byte rcvBuf[] = new byte[500];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(rcvBuf, rcvBuf.length);
    ds.receive(dp);

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(rcvBuf);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(bis));
    Drqst drqst = null;

    Cpacket cp = (Cpacket)ois.readObject();
    drqst =   (Drqst) cp;
    bis.close();

    System.out.println("Received packet type: " +  cp.getPktType());
    System.out.println("Received: " + drqst.getName() + " with " + drqst.getBpub()+ " packet type: " +  drqst.getPktType()  );


    System.out.println("Sending reply");

    Drply drply = new Drply("Hi " + drqst.getName(), bpubKey, "192.168.100.200", pvk);
    System.out.println("Public key: " + bpubKey + "Sign: " + drply.getSign());

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(bos));
    oos.flush();
    oos.writeObject(drply);
    oos.flush();                        

    bos.close();

    DatagramPacket ndp = new DatagramPacket(bos.toByteArray(), bos.toByteArray().length, dp.getAddress(), dp.getPort());
    ds.send(ndp);

    System.out.println("Reply sent.");

    ds.close();

}
```

}

```
 //client.java

 public class TestClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, DataException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();

    KeyPairGenerator kg;
    kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair kp = kg.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey pvk = kp.getPrivate();
    PublicKey pbk = kp.getPublic();
    X509EncodedKeySpec pkeyenc = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pbk.getEncoded());
    byte[] bpubKey= pkeyenc.getEncoded(); 

    Drqst drqst = new Drqst("abc", bpubKey);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(500);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(bos));
    oos.flush();
    oos.writeObject(drqst);
    oos.flush();
          //retrieves byte array
    byte[] sendBuf = bos.toByteArray();
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, ip, 6000);
    ds.send(dp);
    oos.close(); 


    System.out.println("Waiting.... for data"); 
    byte rcvBuf[] = new byte[1000]; 
    DatagramPacket ndp = new DatagramPacket(rcvBuf, rcvBuf.length);
    ds.receive(ndp);

    Drply drp = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(rcvBuf);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(bis));
    drp = (Drply)ois.readObject();
    bis.close();

    System.out.println("Received pkt: " + drp.getName() + " having " + drp.getIp() + " and " + drp.getBpub() + " with Pkt. type " + drp.getPktType());
    System.out.println("Public key: " + drp.getBpub() + "Sign: " + drp.getSign());
    System.out.println("Sig. matching: " + drp.verifySignature());

    ds.close();

}
```

}

Comment: One problem I can spot is that you're calling `toString()` on a `byte[]`. This is not useful. I've seen many questions about this in the past but I can't seem to find any of them at the moment.

Comment: The answer lies in this line. You have to figure out how it returns true or false as Signature class is not posted here. ret = sig.verify(bsign);